# Dependabot configuration in monorepo not using ignore

Tags: github, dependabot

I have a monorepo that has poetry files in several subdirectories. I've currently defined my dependabot configuration to ignore semver major versions, but dependabot is still upgrading to major. Should I try adding using glob patterns with `directory` such that it's iteratively updating.

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "pip" # See documentation for possible values
    directory: "/backend/python" # Location of package manifests
    schedule:
      interval: "monthly"
    labels:
      - "dependencies"
    # Max number of PRs per month
    open-pull-requests-limit: 5
    ignore:
      - dependency-name: "*"
        update-types: ["version-update:semver-major"]
```

my poetry files are located in `/backend/python`, `/backend/python/modules/a`, and `/backend/python/modules/b`